# onSavedInstance in a fragment bundle issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_alert_center, container, false);

if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mItems = (ArrayList<AlertItemI>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("itemBundle");
        }


//Everything else here
}
```

at the bottom i have

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
       super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
       outState.putSerializable("itembundle", mItems);
    }
```

Am I doing this right?
When I debug, it never comes back to the onCreateView() when it should.

Comment: Can you maybe provide us with more detailed question? what is wrong exactly?

Comment: activity1 hosts fragment1, fragment1 opens activity2 that hosts fragment2, fragment2 opens activity3 that hosts fragment3. When I go back from fragment3, it closes activity3 and since the variable mItems has lost it's contents, it closes activity2 and goes back to activity1. I need it to not close activity2. If mItems can be repopulated, it will not close activity 2.

Comment: You have a typo: "itembundle" || "itemBundle".